# For which n does a quadratic congruence have solutions e.g $x^2=83 (modn) $

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, congruences, quadratic-reciprocity

For which n does a quadratic congruence have solutions e.g $x^2=83 \pmod n$

I've tried using the Chinese remainder theorem to break it down, this is what I have so far

$x^2=83 \pmod2 $ has solutions

$x^2=83 \pmod4 $ has no solutions

$x^2=83 \pmod{83}$ has solution

$x^2=83 \pmod{83^2}$ has no solutions

suppose $p\neq 2,83$ then use quadratic reciprocity

$(83/p)=(-1)^{(83-1)(p-1)/4} (p/83)$

Not sure what to do next

Comment: Quadratic reciprocity is the way to go. $x^2\equiv83\bmod n$ has a solution if and only if $x^2\equiv83\bmod{p^r}$ has a solution for every prime power $p^r$ dividing $n$, so this reduces the problem to prime power moduli. For odd primes $p$, there's a solution mod $p^r$ if and only if there's a solution mod $p$, so this reduces the problem to prime moduli (except for $p=2$), and for prime moduli you have quadratic reciprocity. Can you deal with the case $p=2$?

Comment: Are you still here?